inline sourcemaps is not happening when changing it to be inlined?
Inline source maps when i build my angular project/app
I seem to have some problems with my build configuration for angular
I cannot to inline my source maps,
What I've tried:
I've so far tried to set sourceMaps: true in project.json => which resulted in sourcemaps being created as a seperated linked.
I've tried with adding "inlineSourceMap": true, "inlineSources": true in my tsconfig file which did not seem to change anything?
I've also created a seperate gulptask to fix the issue post build, but that didn't fix anything either.
sorry -  for quality of question, i am dwelling in a unfamilar terriorty.
How do i inline sourcemaps?

Angular on it's own does not support it.
Enable building with source maps generated as inline-source-map - Github Issue
Inline SourceMap Option - Github issue

Thank you :D
I ended up making a python script which  could do it for me.

@J.Down Do share the python script to help someone in the future! you can post the answer and mark that as accepted
